# Failed to include details of hotel reservation in Schengen visa application

Tags: visas, schengen, bookings

I just submitted my Schengen visa application. When I printed, I realized that the hotel reservation section was blank. It could be that I did not enter the details or my computer network didn't let it download fully. Then again, the field has an asterisk, so I couldn't have gone past that page if I did not enter the information. What can I do?

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1):

The Embassy would not process your application with no confirmed hotel reservation. However no need to worry you can call up the embassy and submit the required documents again for your application.